# btrfs: how to restore only deleted files in a specific directory?

Tags: data-recovery, btrfs

I have a RAID/LVM volume at `/dev/mapper/vg1-lv1` formatted with the native btrfs tools in Ubuntu 14.04. In that volume I have the highest directory structure like this:

```
datadir/dir1
datadir/dir2
```

Some files in `dir2` got deleted by accident. And I want to recover only those deleted files, not the one that are not deleted or the ones that are in `dir1`.

I am running btrfs restore like this:

```
btrfs restore -v -i -t 12042976395264 --path-regex ^(|datadir(|/dir1(|/.*))) /dev/mapper/vg1-lv1 ./recovered
```

This however, is restoring files in `dir1` as well. And since the `datadir` is very big (TBs size), I don't want to recover everything? How the restore command should be?